# Issue with Laravel debugbar 1.8.*

Tags: laravel, debugging, laravel-4, phpdebugbar

I am facing an issue with `laravel debugbar version 1.8.*` with laravel `4.2`, following are the screenshots for error. Its working on the back-end but getting this weird JS error.

[image]

[image]